# Função PHP retornando sempre NULL

Tags: php

Tenho uma função em PHP que está retornando sempre NULL e não estou conseguindo entender o motivo.

A variável que estou tentando retornar é um array multidimensional. Quando dou um `var_dump` na variável ela está com o valor correto, mas o retornar pela função retorna NULL. Tentei retornar uma string, e também retorna NULL. Sei que o problema está na função mas não consigo encontrar.

A função:

```
function merge($correto, $incremento, $parada){


    $atual=$correto[$incremento];
    $anterior=$correto[$incremento-1];
    if($atual['produto']==$anterior['produto']){
        $correto[$incremento]=array_merge($atual, $anterior);
        unset($correto[$incremento-1]);
        $correto=array_values($correto);
    }else{
        $incremento++;
    }
    if($incremento==$parada){
         return $correto;
    }else{
        $parada=count($correto)-1;
        merge($correto, $incremento, $parada);
    }

}
```

Estou chamando a função assim:

```
$resultado=merge($correto, 0, count($correto)-1);
```

A variável `$correto` é um array multidimensional. Estou fazendo um merge entre as posições que contém o mesmo valor para `$correto['produto']`

Exemplo da variável `$correto`:

```
array(14) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["produto"]=>
    string(7) "ABACAXI"
    ["medida"]=>
    string(8) "Unidades"
    ["valor"]=>
    float(5)
    ["2,2016"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["quant"]=>
      float(35)
      ["total"]=>
      float(175)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["produto"]=>
    string(11) "ACUCAR 5 KG"
    ["medida"]=>
    string(8) "Unidades"
    ["valor"]=>
    float(8.48)
    ["2,2016"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["quant"]=>
      float(13)
      ["total"]=>
      float(110.24)
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["produto"]=>
    string(11) "ACUCAR 5 KG"
    ["medida"]=>
    string(8) "Unidades"
    ["valor"]=>
    float(8.48)
    ["1,2016"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["quant"]=>
      float(5)
      ["total"]=>
      float(42.4)
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["produto"]=>
    string(11) "ACUCAR 5 KG"
    ["medida"]=>
    string(8) "Unidades"
    ["valor"]=>
    float(8.48)
    ["1,2015"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["quant"]=>
      float(11)
      ["total"]=>
      float(93.28)
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["produto"]=>
    string(11) "ACUCAR 5 KG"
    ["medida"]=>
    string(8) "Unidades"
    ["valor"]=>
    float(8.48)
    ["2,2015"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["quant"]=>
      float(13)
      ["total"]=>
      float(110.24)
    }
  }
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    ["produto"]=>
    string(20) "ALFACE CRESPA VERDE "
    ["medida"]=>
    string(8) "Unidades"
    ["valor"]=>
    float(2.5)
    ["2,2016"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["quant"]=>
      float(10)
      ["total"]=>
      float(25)
    }
  }
  [6]=>
  array(4) {
    ["produto"]=>
    string(16) "ALHO DESCASCADO "
    ["medida"]=>
    string(10) "Quilograma"
    ["valor"]=>
    float(18)
    ["2,2016"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["quant"]=>
      float(15)
      ["total"]=>
      float(270)
    }
  }
  [7]=>
  array(4) {
    ["produto"]=>
    string(9) "AMENDOIM "
    ["medida"]=>
    string(7) "Pacotes"
    ["valor"]=>
    float(8.15)
    ["2,2015"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["quant"]=>
      float(10)
      ["total"]=>
      float(81.5)
    }
  }
  [8]=>
  array(4) {
    ["produto"]=>
    string(9) "AMENDOIM "
    ["medida"]=>
    string(7) "Pacotes"
    ["valor"]=>
    float(8.15)
    ["1,2015"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["quant"]=>
      float(16)
      ["total"]=>
      float(130.4)
    }
  }
  [9]=>
  array(4) {
    ["produto"]=>
    string(9) "AMENDOIM "
    ["medida"]=>
    string(7) "Pacotes"
    ["valor"]=>
    float(8.15)
    ["1,2016"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["quant"]=>
      float(5)
      ["total"]=>
      float(40.75)
    }
  }
  [10]=>
  array(4) {
    ["produto"]=>
    string(9) "AMENDOIM "
    ["medida"]=>
    string(7) "Pacotes"
    ["valor"]=>
    float(8.15)
    ["2,2016"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["quant"]=>
      float(4)
      ["total"]=>
      float(32.6)
    }
  }
  [11]=>
  array(4) {
    ["produto"]=>
    string(14) "AMIDO DE MILHO"
    ["medida"]=>
    string(4) "Saco"
    ["valor"]=>
    float(47.58)
    ["2,2016"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["quant"]=>
      float(1)
      ["total"]=>
      float(47.58)
    }
  }
  [12]=>
  array(4) {
    ["produto"]=>
    string(14) "AMIDO DE MILHO"
    ["medida"]=>
    string(4) "Saco"
    ["valor"]=>
    float(47.58)
    ["2,2015"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["quant"]=>
      float(2)
      ["total"]=>
      float(95.16)
    }
  }
  [13]=>
  array(4) {
    ["produto"]=>
    string(14) "AMIDO DE MILHO"
    ["medida"]=>
    string(4) "Saco"
    ["valor"]=>
    float(47.58)
    ["1,2015"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["quant"]=>
      float(1)
      ["total"]=>
      float(47.58)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo do array que está a injetar para a função sff. Eu acho que é porque só existe um return, ou seja, caso não entre no `if($incremento==$parada)` vai returnar sempre null

Comment: @Miguel, editei a questão com um exemplo. No caso, sempre vai entrar no ´if($incremento==$parada)´ para qualquer valor de `$correto`. Coloquei um `echo` dentro deste `if`, e é certo que sempre entra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta um return no `else` também. Tente assim:

```
function merge($correto, $incremento, $parada){


    $atual=$correto[$incremento];
    $anterior=$correto[$incremento-1];
    if($atual['produto']==$anterior['produto']){
        $correto[$incremento]=array_merge($atual, $anterior);
        unset($correto[$incremento-1]);
        $correto=array_values($correto);
    }else{
        $incremento++;
    }
    if($incremento==$parada){
        return $correto;
    }else{
        $parada=count($correto)-1;
        return merge($correto, $incremento, $parada);
    }

}
```

Parece-me que está a querer chamar a `merge()` recursivamente, para isso precisa de retornar a função com os novos dados definidos nessa mesma execução da função

Comment: Muito obrigada @Miguel, era isso mesmo!

Comment: De nada @AmandaLima